# Finding item at index i of an iterable (syntactic sugar)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, iterator

I know that `maps`, `range`, `filters` etc. in `python3` return iterables, and only calculate value when required. Suppose that there is a `map M`. I want to print the `i^th` element of M.

One way would be to iterate till `i^th` value, and print it:

```py
for _ in range(i):
    next(M)
print(next(M))
```

The above takes `O(i)` time, where I have to find the `i^th` value.

Another way is to convert to a list, and print the `i^th` value:

```py
print(list(M)[i])
```

This however, takes `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space (where `n` is the size of the list from which the map `M` is created). However, this suits the so-called "Pythonic way of writing one-liners."

I was wondering if there is a syntactic sugar to minimise writing in the first way? (i.e., if there is a way which takes `O(i)` time, no extra space, and is more suited to the "Pythonic way of writing".)

Comment: Are you specifically talking about `map`? because `range` objects *are* indexable in O(1) time. `range(1, 100)[-1]` returns 99

Comment: `maps` and `filters` basically, although I didn't know about `range` objects being indexable in O(1) time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
from itertools import islice

i = 3
print(next(islice(iterable), i, i + 1))
```

This outputs `'3'`.

It actually doesn't matter what you use as the `stop` argument, as long as you call `next` once.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DeepSpace for the reference to the official docs, I found the following:

```py
from more_itertools import nth

print(nth(M, i))
```

It prints the element at `i^th` index of the iterable.